# Stop background worker inside DoWork C#

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

There is a loop inside my background worker's do_work operation. I want my background worker to work some amount of time and then I want my application to shut down. Here is my try :

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
dt = DateTime.Now;

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        //do some work

        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - dt;
        if (ts.TotalMilliseconds >= 10 * 1000)
        {
            break;
            // and stop background worker
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what happens? What is the problem?

Comment: Yes, this will indeed break out of the `while` loop and exit the method (if there is nothing else after the loop). Obviously, you need to set `dt` **before** starting the worker.

Comment: You're missing a `}`.  Besides that, what isn't working about this?  What behaviour do you expect and what behaviour do you observe?  How are they different?

Comment: As I observe, program keeps running, but it's supposed to end..

Comment: Why is it supposed to end?  Stopping a worker thread does not stop the application.  The code you've shown are scraps cut out of a program - it's hard to tell what the rest of the program is meant to be doing if we can't see it.

Comment: What does the "do some work" part look like? And what do you expect should happen?

Comment: We can help if you post short but complete sample demonstrating the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the event `RunWorkerCompleted` and close the application inside the handler.

```
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_Completed;
```

Handler:

```
void worker_Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

The question is a bit unclear but the code you provided should work. This answer assumes the problem is closing the application when it's done.